# Using %-sign (percentage symbol) in a SQL query with objective-c

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sqlite

So, exactly what the title states. I'd like to use a query like this:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Devices WHERE Location LIKE '%@%'", name];
```

What it basically asks, is for example: `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Devices WHERE Location LIKE 'N%'` . Then I'd like to find all the computers in building N, including all sublocations (like N33).

The question is: how do I insert the %-sign in the query? Currently, it shows `'N'` only...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use two % signs to escape %:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Devices WHERE Location LIKE '%@%%'", name];
```

(of course, you need to [sanitize your input](http://xkcd.com/327/), or use a parameterized query in the first place, to prevent SQL injection attacks)

Comment: On a side note: it seems to be working, but the NSLog of this query still doesn't show the %-sign. The query works nevertheless, but any idea why `NSLog(querySQL)` doesn't show the %?

Comment: @Joetjah: It parses the % as format specifier. Try `NSLog(@"%@", querySql);`